# How do I Resolve an Alias with Node Sass in a .mjs Script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, node-sass

My project's structure has a SCSS library for global settings and such, and main component scss modules are elsewhere with their corresponding component files. I have my Webpack set up to resolve a path alias `@` when it builds, so my usage of lines like `@import "@/src/scss/variables/blah-blah.scss"` works out just fine when running the project.

Conversely, I have some utility scripts i'm using to do SCSS benchmarking, just some compile and analyze operations to help illustrate our performance gains while we work on style changes. I have these built using the `.mjs` file extension, which I don't think is important here, it's just helping play nice with Typescript.

So when Node Sass encounters a path like `@import "@/src/scss/variables/blah-blah.scss"` it won't resolve the path. No surprise there, but I can't seem to locate a best solution to just help resolve the path within my script, rather than add on NPM packages to do a seemingly simple job. How should I be approaching this?

Error comes up from `await sass.render()`

```js
import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
import sass from "node-sass";
import tildeImporter from "node-sass-tilde-importer";
import { resolve } from "path";

export const compileCSS = async module => {
  const input = `src/components/${module}/scss/module.scss`;
  const output = `stats/css/${module}.css`;
  await sass.render(
    {
      file: resolve(input),
      importer: tildeImporter,
      outputStyle: "expanded",
      outFile: resolve(output),
      sourceMap: true
    },
    async function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        await console.log(module, "COMPILE ERROR", error.message);
      } else {
        writeFileSync(resolve(output), result);
        return result;
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Further research shows me that Node Sass does not currently have a great way to enable this, though some ideas appear in the works.

I made a work around by converting my stats gathering operations into a Webpack loader module that analyzes and spits out my data in between steps to pack the compiled styles into the bundle. This way I get the alias path resolved and simplify the dev experience. It's a better solution than I had set out for so I'm pleased.